# Coin change with limited number of coins

Tags: c, algorithm, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem, coin-change

I have written a program for generating subset sum which might be used in this problem which states:

> Suppose,  you have 3 $1-coins, 2
>   $2-coins, 3 $5-coins, 1 $10-coin,
>   there are 4 ways to obtain $10 from
>   those coins. If there are n1 $X1
>   coins, n2 $X2 coins.... nm $Xm coins,
>   how many ways can we obtain $X from
>   these limited number of coins?

If we create a set of { X1, X1..... X1, X2, X2.......... X2, ..., ..., ............, Xm, Xm... Xm}, and then run Subset summing on it, surely we can get a result for $X.
But I could not find a way to use the sets {n1, n2, n3.... nm} , {X1, X2, X3.... Xm}.
A friend told me that it is a variation of knapsack problem, but I am not sure, how.

This is a partial code of what I have written :

```
ways[0]=1, mylim=0;
for(i=0;i<count;i++){
    if(mylim+coins[i]<=LIMIT) mylim+=coins[i];
    else mylim=LIMIT;

    for(j=mylim; j>=coins[i];j--){
        ways[j]=(ways[j]+ways[j-coins[i]])%MOD;
    }
}
```

It would be great for me if you are kind enough to explain a bit elaborately.

**EDIT**:
This question is more suitable for stackexchange for computer science, but since it is an old question of mine, I'm rather editing it here.

This problem can be solved with **Inclusion Exclusion** principle, and it comes handy *when we have coin values fixed but number of each coin varying with each query*.

Suppose, *ways[v]* is ways of making *$v* with *$x1*, *$x2*, .. *$xm*, each being used as many times as needed. Now, if we are using only *n1* numbers of *$x1*, we have to subtract the configurations using at least (*n1* + 1) numbers of *$x1* ( which is actually *ways*[*v - (n1 + 1)x1*] ). Moreover, if we are using only *n2* numbers of *$x2*, we have to subtract *ways*[*v - (n2 + 1)x2*] as well, and etc.

Now, we have twice subtracted the configurations where at least (*n1* + 1) *$x1* and (*n2* + 1) *$x2* are used, hence we need to add *ways*[*v -(n1 + 1)x1 - (n2 + 1)x2*] and etc.

In particular, if,

**N** = set of configurations where all coins are used as many as possible,

**Ai** = set of configurations where at least *ni* + 1 numbers of *$xi* is used, for 1 <= *i* <= *m*, then

the result we are seeking = |**N**| - |**A1**| - |**A2**| .. - |**Am**| + |**A1** and **A2**| + |**A1** and **A3**| + ... - |**A1** and **A2** and **A3**| .....

The code which computes number of configurations with unlimited coins is actually simpler:

```
ways[0]=1;
for( int i = 0 ; i < count ; i++){
    for( int j = coins[i] ; j < ways.size() ; j++ ){
        ways[j] += ways[j-coins[i]];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's assume all your `ni` are `1`.

Let `ways[j] = number of ways of obtaining sum j`.

You can compute this like so (this is what you're doing, but I don't know why you named your variable `primes`).

```
ways[0] = 1
for i = 1 to m do
    for j = myLim downto X[i] do
        ways[j] += ways[j - X[i]];
```

This means you only use each coin of value `Xi` once. You can add another loop to use it at least once and at most `ni` times however:

```
ways[0] = 1
for i = 1 to m do
    for times = 1 to n[i] do // use Xi one time, then two times, then three, ..., then ni
        for j = myLim downto times*X[i] do
            ways[j] += ways[j - times*X[i]];
```

You can still apply your modulo and compute your limit, I left those out for simplicity.

Comment: Well, using primes is easy to explain why. I copied it from a code which asks for prime valued coin. :P . And using 'times' wont help... I think I did just that, but it ended with larger answer than usual. MAs MathWorld says, GCD is needed.... I am trying to extend the idea. Thanks a lot for your answer :).

Comment: Can you please explain this answer further? I got coin change problem working but having trouble when the coins are limited e.g. 1p = 6 coins, 2p = 10 coins etc.

Comment: I believe the j loop should be populated in an increasing order since you are looking at previous ways[j]. Am I correct?

Comment: @marti no, because then, in the same iteration, you would be using already computed values, potentially using `Xi` more times than allowed.

Answer (score -4):

The problem is named "The coin problem" and is known to be NP-hard.

You may learn a little  about it  [here.](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CoinProblem.html)

Comment: I don't see how that's related. The OP's question mentions no GCD and asks for something different.

Comment: @IVlad He also says *A friend told me that it is a variation of knapsack problem, but I am not sure, how.* The problem has a name, and has been studied a lot. It's not a toy problem.

Comment: that may be so, but it's definitely not what you linked to.

Comment: @IVlad I think it is. If the GCD is greater than 1 there are more solutions, you can get trivially by using sub-multiples. (i.e. replace a $10 coin by two $5 coins). But you have first to solve the hard problem. Just remove the non GCD=1 coins, solve the problem and then add those combinations where you can stuff up the higher denominations (non GCD =1)

Comment: The linked problem seems to be about `largest nonrepresentable amounts` - I don't get the connection to `how many ways can we obtain $X`. (It mentions `No closed-form solution is known [generally]`, which, combined with your `known to be NP-hard` above makes me ask: Are you thinking of the right problem, but providing a link to a (loosely) related, but different one?)